# Using System.Numerics.dll in Unity3D UWP

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, system.numerics

I want to use the some classes of the System.Numerics assembly in my own DLL project which is used in some other projects too. But I run into problems with Unity3D targeting UWP Hololens. In editor it works out of the box but when I build the project Unity complains
`error CS7069: Reference to type 'Vector3' claims it is defined in 'System.Numerics', but it could not be found`

I copied System.Numerics.Vector.DLL from *Unity\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\4.7.1-api*. 4.7.1 should be the one according to this [Unity blog post](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/03/28/updated-scripting-runtime-in-unity-2018-1-what-does-the-future-hold/). I tried out different versions (even 4.5) but it does not work either.

My own DLL uses 4.7.1 as well (tried 4.6.1 at the beginning). Now the editor complains that `Loading script assembly "Assets/DLLs/System.Numerics.Vectors.dll" failed!`. Thus I excluded the editor platform.

As next I tried using System.Numerics.dll (i.e. not just the Vectors). Now the results are even stranger:
`CS0433: The type 'Vector3' exists in both 'System.Numerics.Vectors` ... `System.Numerics.`

My own DLL is completely in plain old C#, nothing special, no file access, ...

So how can I do this? Yes I know there is Vector3D class in Unity :) But I need to build a DLL that is used outside Unity.

---

### Update:

I removed all direct calls to System.Numeric namespace classes. Now the UWP solution builds but with a bunch of post-processing errors:
`Reference rewriter: Error: type 'System.Numerics.Vector3' doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from ARSceneSerialization.dll at ARSceneSerialization.ARKeyFrame.`

I think this sounds bad.

Comment: i you try the 4.5 version at MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\4.5?

Comment: I had and just repeated it witout success: One DLL (System.Numerics) but the _ exists in both_ message

Comment: @Programmer (forgot the @ in the last message) I guess it's a Unity UWP specific problem, simply not supporting System.Numerics.DLL on this platform

Comment: Can you you try to build for Windows standalone? No UWP this time and see if there is an issue

Comment: @Programmer Windows standalone and Android are building fine

Comment: That's weird. What's your Unity version and target framework set to?

Comment: @Programmer 2018.1.6 and UWP / Hololens / Latest installed versions. Scripting backend is .NET, Runtime 4.x equivalent, API level 4.x. IL2CPP only for release as it is aweful to debug during development.

Comment: Interesting. I suspect that the issue is how you built the DLL. I am not entirely sure since I haven't made a build for Hololens. Before you build your dll, add  `C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll` reference to it but going to Project > Add Reference > Browse. Also, add the `System.Numerics` reference it in `MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\4.5`. Now, try to build it. If you still get errors, delete those `System.Numerics` and `System.Numerics.Vectors` from your project and try again

Comment: @Programmer This might be the way to get it running. A separate project for building the  Unity/UWP DLL. For the moment I have to stop here as it took too much time for a nice to have feature. Maybe I try it at the weekend just out of curiosity. Anyway, many many thanks to you and Bijan

Comment: Yes and the proper way to building a manage plugin is by creating  a new VS project different from Unity the add the references required. I am sure that might fix your issue. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Unity cannot find the assembly because of the folder name in which you placed the DLL

According to [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html)

> Always place plug-ins in a folder called **Plugins** for them to be
>   detected by Unity.

Comment: I tried this before but no chance. My DLL is written in C# so this does not apply according to the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html) Other DLLs are working fine in my DLL directory. Anyway thanks! I will add that to the question.

Comment: @Kay also you check the properties of the dll file to see if it's blocked by OS for some reason (seeing the unblock button means so)

Comment: I have got _Any platform_ with _Editor_ as the only one in excluded platforms. My own DLL has no exclusions just any platform